# Adding to macro that creates graph from multiple sheets in excel

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I have an excel file with multiple sheets labelled  HI12981001.asvp, HI19281002.asvp, HI19281003.asvp etc.

In each sheet are 2 columns with no headers.  I am using the macro below to create a scatter graph of the data in these 2 columns from each sheet.  The problem is I have to manually change the series name for each sheet.

I am looking for help to build on this macro so that I can get excel to look at a list (i.e. HI12981001.asvp, HI19281002.asvp, HI19281003.asvp.. and create a data series in the main chart for each sheet or simple go through the entire book and create a graph with the series name the same as the sheet name.

Here is the macro for just the first three sheets

```
Sub zx()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Chrt As Chart
Dim Srs As Series

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set Chrt = wb.Charts.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
Chrt.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
Chrt.Name = "SVP Profiles"

Set Srs = Chrt.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
Srs.Name = "HI12981001.asvp"
Set sh = wb.Sheets("HI12981001.asvp")
Srs.XValues = "=" & sh.Name & "!" & sh.UsedRange.Columns(2).Address
Srs.Values = "=" & sh.Name & "!" & sh.UsedRange.Columns(1).Address

Set Srs = Chrt.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
Srs.Name = "HI12981002.asvp"
Set sh = wb.Sheets("HI12981002.asvp")
Srs.XValues = "=" & sh.Name & "!" & sh.UsedRange.Columns(2).Address
Srs.Values = "=" & sh.Name & "!" & sh.UsedRange.Columns(1).Address



 Set Srs = Chrt.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    Srs.Name = "HI12981003.asvp"
    Set sh = wb.Sheets("HI12981003.asvp")
    Srs.XValues = "=" & sh.Name & "!" & sh.UsedRange.Columns(2).Address
 Srs.Values = "=" & sh.Name & "!" & sh.UsedRange.Columns(1).Address


 End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub zx()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Chrt As Chart


   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   Set Chrt = wb.Charts.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
   Chrt.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
   Chrt.Name = "SVP Profiles"


   'add the series
   AddNewSeries "HI12981001.asvp", wb, Chrt
   AddNewSeries "HI12981002.asvp", wb, Chrt
   AddNewSeries "HI12981003.asvp", wb, Chrt

End Sub

'Add new series to chart 'cht', using sheet 'sheetName'
'    in Workbook 'wb'
Sub AddNewSeries(sheetName As String, wb As Workbook, cht As Chart)

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim Srs As Series

    Set Srs = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    Srs.Name = sheetName
    Set sh = wb.Sheets(sheetName)
    Srs.XValues = "=" & sh.Name & "!" & sh.UsedRange.Columns(2).Address
    Srs.Values = "=" & sh.Name & "!" & sh.UsedRange.Columns(1).Address

End Sub
```